# How to increase the size of a docker volume using the compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a docker stack with a few services with their data stored on an external volume. The volume driver is the rexray/dobs (for digitalocean block spaces)

The definition for the volume is like so

```
version: "3"
services:

   ...

volume_name:
driver: rexray/dobs
driver_opts:
  size: 2
```

The above automatically creates for me a 2GB block storage volume.

I would like to upgrade the size to something higher. Simply changing

```
size: 2
```

to

```
size: 3 #or something higher
```

and running

```
docker stack deploy ...
```

does not work.

Is there a way to increase the size of the already existing volume using instructions from the docker compose file?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Snowball I never did

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you find an alternative? Looks like rexray is no longer maintained :(

Comment: The project got pulled. So i never got to the end of the rabbit hole. :D